# "振聾發聵" in English?

Tags: phrase

This question is about possible translations of "振聾發聵" in English.

Figuratively, this phrase is used to describe someone's article is penetrating and insightful. I know this. Nevertheless, I am seeking after a more succinct, pithy word in English to translate it.

Thank you so much for your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

**A Chinese-English Dictionary**

> rouse the deaf, enlighten the benighted
>
> 先生这番议论, 真可谓之振聋发聩。
>
> Xiānsheng zhè fān yìlùn, zhēn kěwèi zhī zhènlóngfākuì.
>
> Your arguments, sir, would **make a deaf man hear and a blind man see**.

Make a deaf man hear and a blind man see is a nice phrase.

**CC-CEDICT**

> lit. so loud that even the deaf can hear (idiom); **rousing even the apathetic**

rousing even the apathetic is nice too.